# Qual tipo de erro é esse e como posso resolver Django?

Tags: python, django, formulário

Eu tinha feito uma mundança pequena no meu 'pessoaCreate()' que é view que está sendo referenciada nesse caminho, porém agora ele fica me dando esse erro, sendo que até dei um 'CTRL Z' nas mudanças que eu fiz.

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcCcG.png)

Alguém sabe me dizer pelo menos que tipo de problema é esse e qual a possivel causa (de forma um pouco mais especifica)?